# Erro de implementação Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, programação-estruturada, bubblesort

Boa tarde a todos. No momento estou tentando implementar o Bubble Sort, o método de ordenação, porem eu estou com dificuldades para imprimir os valores, que esses valores são random, usando a função Rand.

O erro no qual eu estou enfrentado é, os valores ele sai em hexadecimais.
os valores não são random.

O que eu tenho em mente, é imprimir um vetor de tamanho 10,000. 
No qual todos seja randômicos. mas eu me perdi na logica que estava tendo.

Essa é a minha primeira idea. porem a segunda é implementa 7 métodos ordenação em um programa só. com o tempo de cada um monitorado e imprimido na tela

ps: sei que os valores são altos, não irei mostra os valores ao imprimir cada um deles. vai ser imprimido tudo de uma vez só, no final será mostrado o tempo que cada um demorou para completa o método de ordenação.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10000

using namespace std;

void BubbleSort(int vetor[MAX], int tamanho){
    int temp = 0;
    bool trocou = false;
    for(int i = tamanho - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        for(int j = 1; j < tamanho; j++){
            if(vetor[j] < vetor[j - 1]){
                temp = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = vetor[j - 1];
                vetor[j - 1] = temp;
                trocou = true;
            }
        }
        if(!trocou)
            break;
    }
}

void MostraVetor(int vet[MAX]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        cout << vet << " " << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int vet[MAX];
    // inicializa o gerador de números randômicos para preenchermos o vetor com números aleatórios
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        vet[MAX] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    cout << "O vetor foi preenchido aleatoriamente assim: " << "\n" << endl;
    MostraVetor(vet);
    cout << "Depois de ordenado: " << "\n" << endl;
    BubbleSort(vet,10000);
    MostraVetor(vet);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Israel,

Você tem erros nos loops que criou.

Seu primeiro loop, você gera o número aleatório, porém sempre coloca o número na mesma posição do array, pois deixou fixo o define MAX na posição do array:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    vet[MAX] = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

O correto aqui, é você utilizar a variável do for:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    vet[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

No outro loop que você exibe o array, você não exibiu a posição do array, colocou apenas o próprio array, com isso você exibiu a posição da memória do array, e esses são os números hexadecimais que você citou:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    cout << vet << " " << endl;
}
```

O correto aqui, novamente é utilizar a variável do for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    cout << vet[i] << " " << endl;
}
```

> Obs.: Você criou o define MAX, mas ainda sim, deixou diversos números
>   no fonte, já que criou o define, o ideal é utilizar ele em todos os
>   lugares

---

Efetuando todas as correções necessárias, seu código ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 10000

using namespace std;

void BubbleSort(int vetor[MAX], int tamanho){
    int temp = 0;
    bool trocou = false;
    for(int i = tamanho - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        for(int j = 1; j < tamanho; j++){
            if(vetor[j] < vetor[j - 1]){
                temp = vetor[j];
                vetor[j] = vetor[j - 1];
                vetor[j - 1] = temp;
                trocou = true;
            }
        }
        if(!trocou)
            break;
    }
}

void MostraVetor(int vet[MAX]){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        cout << vet[i] << " " << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int vet[MAX];
    // inicializa o gerador de números randômicos para preenchermos o vetor com números aleatórios
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        vet[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }

    cout << "O vetor foi preenchido aleatoriamente assim: " << "\n" << endl;
    MostraVetor(vet);
    cout << "Depois de ordenado: " << "\n" << endl;
    BubbleSort(vet,MAX);
    MostraVetor(vet);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja que troquei em alguns pontos o 10000 pelo MAX, com isso, alterando o valor de MAX, seu código continua funcionando.

Comment: Ah! muito obrigado, Mendes. como eu não percebi esses erros. muito obrigado.